# Unable to see all the images i paint and can't get a JScrollPane to work

Tags: java, image, swing, jscrollpane, paintcomponent

So my problem is i'm painting to many images to see and i can't get the JScrollPane bars to show up so i can look though all the images.

My code is this.

You will need a image 40 by 40 or get a error. The file name are "Wall.gif", "DefualtTileBackup.gif", "Character.gif", "metal3.jpg" and "DefualtTileBackup.gif"

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.net.*;

public class DrawImage extends JPanel {
    private Image image;
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    private char[][] fieldMap = {
            {'$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$'},
            {'$','S','M','@','Z','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','$'},
            {'$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$'},
            {'$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$'},
            {'$','S','M','@','Z','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','$'},
            {'$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$'},
            {'$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$'},
            {'$','S','M','@','Z','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','$'},
            {'$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$'},
            {'$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$'},
            {'$','S','M','@','Z','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','$'},
            {'$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$'},
            {'$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$'},
            {'$','S','M','@','Z','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','$'},
            {'$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$'},
            {'$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$'},
            {'$','S','M','@','Z','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','$'},
            {'$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$'},
            {'$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$'},
            {'$','S','M','@','Z','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','$'},
            {'$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$'},
            {'$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$'},
            {'$','S','M','@','Z','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','$'},
            {'$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$'},

        };
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawImage");
        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(new DrawImage()));
    }

public DrawImage() {
    super();
    setVisible(true);   

}


private URL getURL(String filename) {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = this.getClass().getResource(filename);
    }

    catch (Exception e) { }
    return url;
}
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    //create an instance of Graphics2D
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    //fill the background with black
    g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);

    //draw the image
    for(int K = 0; K < this.fieldMap.length ; K = K+1){
    for(int J = 0; J < this.fieldMap[K].length; J = J + 1){
    g2d.drawImage(imagePlacer(this.fieldMap[K][J]),(J*40),(K*40), this );
        } // loop Y end
    }// loop X end
}// paint end

public Image imagePlacer(char tiles){


            try {
                switch(tiles){

                case('$'):
                    System.out.println("Wall, $");
                     image = tk.getImage(getURL("Wall.gif"));
                     break;


                case('F'):
                    System.out.println("Floor, #");
                     image = tk.getImage(getURL("DefualtTileBackup.gif"));
                     break;


                case('@'):
                    System.out.println("Character, @");
                     image = tk.getImage(getURL("Character.gif"));
                     break;


                case('M'):

                    System.out.println("Monster, !");
                     image = tk.getImage(getURL("metal3.jpg"));
                     break;

                default:
                        System.out.println("defualt,?");
                        image = tk.getImage(getURL("DefualtTileBackup.gif"));
                      break;

                    // end default
                }// end switch
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    return image;
}//end method
}// end class
```

The program seems to be working correctly but I don't get scroll bars.

Comment: You've described a problem and how you can't do it, but have so far not asked a question.  Do you have a question?

Comment: I don't see how but I added a bit more in a edit. my problem is i can't get any interaction with the JScrollPane so i can see the rest of the map.

Comment: *"I don't see how"*  Add a request for information, followed by a '?'.  E.G.  **"How do I get the scroll-bars to appear?"**  (It is not rocket science.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide a size for the panel. As far as I can see the panel doesn't contain any other components, thus the layoutmanager would normally try to fit it into the available space.

If I counted correctly you have a 18x18 grid, thus the size of your panel would need to be at least 720x720 (I assume you have 18x18 tiles of 40x40 images). Try calling `setMinimumSize(new Dimension(720,720))` on your panel.

*Edit*:

As @camickr correctly pointed out, `JScrollPane` will use the preferred size of the panel. Thus you might try to either set it externally (`setPreferredSize(...)`)  or, since you're already extending the panel and the subclass has the information it needs, override the panel's `getPreferredSize()` to return the calculated preferred size.

Comment: +1 for the size problem. However the solution should be to override the getPreferredSize() method to return the proper dimension of the panel. The scrollpane works with the preferred size, not the minimum size.

Comment: Sorry i didn't reply sooner, but, I've been kinda busy with college. So i had tried your first solution with the setMinimumSize eariler in the week but didn't have a chance to reply. Well it didn't work as camickr points out. I just tried the PreferredSize method and yes it to 7200x7200 and it seems to be working. Thank you for your help everyone. Also is there a good reference for the inner workings of swing? Conventions for Swing seem to be the first thing I leave out.

Comment: @JayCD [Oracle's Swing Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/swing/) should provide the information you need (e.g. how layouting works etc.)

Answer (score 4):

another issues

1) please change `public void paint(Graphics g) {` to the `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {`,

for painting to the `Swing JComponent` use method `paintComponent()`

2) `frame.setVisible(true);` must be last code line in the main method

3) better would be put `Image` as [Icon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to the [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) and by using [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) place to the [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)